# Using Excel Add-in xlwings gives end of file error

Tags: python, excel, office-addins, excel-addins, xlwings

I have installed xlwings in anaconda's base environment and installed the excel add-in as well. I have been able to import User-Defined Functions. However, recently, it has started to bug out. Whenever I click on the xlwings ribbon in excel, it gives the following error:

> Input past end of file (Error 62)

[image]

Any button I press in the xlwings ribbon gives the same result. I have xlwings exclusively for UDF use, so this has paralyzed my ability to get any use out of it. Any help in getting this add-in rehabilitated is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's some more info as per @BigBen's request)

I clicked the 'Import Functions' button in the xlwings ribbon and it gave me the screenshotted error. I clicked debug and it brought me here:

[image]

Comment: If you press Debug, are you taking to the offending line of code?

Comment: @BigBen, thanks for answering. I tried that out just now. I clicked the 'Import Functions' button in the xlwings ribbon and it gave me the screenshotted error. I clicked debug and it brought me here. I'm not familiar enough with VBA or complex add-ins to understand much of what's going on here. I can't figure out how to add an image to a comment so I'll add it as an idet to my question.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/850

Comment: @BigBen very helpful. This was the exact same issue and my problem is solved now. I'm not sure how to select your comment as the winning answer (cause it's a comment, not officially an answer?). Thanks!

Comment: @BigBen if you post this as an answer, I'll be happy to select it and close this question out. Otherwise I'll post an answer myself so future searchers can find it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be the same issue as [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/850).

> And this is what xlwings.conf looks like on my desktop:
> [image]

To fix, as commented [here](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/850#issuecomment-380803268):

> Not quite sure how it ended up like this but fix your config file so it reads:
>
> ```
> "INTERPRETER","C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"
> ```